# No limits on quote nesting

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering, blockquote

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > broken layout

I think that a large number of nested quotes shouldn't break the layout of the site Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are you trying to report unlimited nested blockquotes as a bug?

Comment: That seems to be it, yes. They don't exactly break the page layout, but it looks rather strange. On the other hand, it's hard to say that there should be a limit, or what the limit should be.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think this is a bug, can I write somewhere else besides meta?

Comment: Meta is the correct place to report issues such as this one, the confusion is stemming from the fact that your SO question is asking about a similar problem with your react environment, which meta is *not* for. so you need to be very clear here that you're asking about the site, not your problem.

Comment: @KevinB ok, I edited the report

Comment: How is it broken? What do you expect instead?

Comment: Note that most of these "features" are exploited already in our sandbox: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363285 and those don't need repeats or bug reports.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I {do some ill-advised thing}."

Answer (score 13):

This is somewhat of an edge-case, this doesn't occur often enough for it to really *need* a solution. There isn't a scenario where a question *should* have deeply nested quotes so any time that occurs, it should just be edited. You don't need to show a blockquote nested 20 times to make your point, you could do it with 5 and say you wanted to limit it to 3, the solution can be adapted to whatever your actual requirements are.